# PyGears TypeError: [0], cannot saturate 'Int[10]' to a different base type 'Fixp[8, 16]'

Tags: python, pygears

I'm trying to make a simple module called Neuron. Idea is to multiply input pixel value with weight and then accumulate. After accumulation, the result should be added to the bias value and then send it back to the output.

Code is below, the error I'm gettig is this one:

> TypeError: [0], cannot saturate 'Int[10]' to a different base type
> 'Fixp[8, 16]' when resolving return type "type_saturate(data, t,
> limits)"

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
from pygears.typing import Queue, Tuple, Fixp
from pygears.lib import mul, accum, qround, saturate, queuemap, add
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen

@gear
def neuron (din: Queue[Tuple[Fixp[4, 16], Fixp[4, 16]]], *, bias):
  return din \
    | queuemap(f=mul) \
    | accum(init=Fixp[8, 32](0)) \
    | add(Fixp[8,32](bias)) \
    | qround \
    | saturate(t=Fixp[8, 16])
  
neuron(Intf(Queue[Tuple[Fixp[4, 16], Fixp[4, 16]]]),bias=3)
 
hdlgen('/neuron',outdir='./temp_mlp')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module `qround` is connected as a producer to the `saturate` module, and the `qround` module outputs data in the integer format, `Int[10]` in your example as the error suggests. The `saturate` module can only operate on data types of the same base type, i.e. it can saturate and `Int` to a smaller `Int`, or a `Fixp` to a smaller `Fixp`.

My guess is that you wanted an `Int[8]` output, since you've already used `qround`

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
from pygears.typing import Queue, Tuple, Fixp, Int
from pygears.lib import mul, accum, qround, saturate, queuemap, add
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen

@gear
def neuron (din: Queue[Tuple[Fixp[4, 16], Fixp[4, 16]]], *, bias):
  return din \
    | queuemap(f=mul) \
    | accum(init=Fixp[8, 32](0)) \
    | add(Fixp[8,32](bias)) \
    | qround \
    | saturate(t=Int[8])

neuron(Intf(Queue[Tuple[Fixp[4, 16], Fixp[4, 16]]]),bias=3)

hdlgen('/neuron',outdir='./temp_mlp')
```